# basic4android - regex match with url

Tags: regex, basic4android

I have the following regex pattern for testing a url and it works fine with all online regex testers including b4a's original regex tester(https://b4x.com:51041/regex_ws/index.html) but not in code!!

```
 Sub Validate(Url As String)As String
    Dim Pattern As String=$"^(https:\/\/t\.me\/|https:\/\/telegram\.me\/)[a-z0-9_]{3,15}[a-z0-9]$"$
    Dim matcher1 As Matcher
    matcher1 = Regex.Matcher(Url,Pattern)
    Return matcher1.Find
End Sub
```

And my Url is

Https:// telegram . me (+ something like 'myChannel' with no spaces ofcurse,its just stacks's editor that won't allow tg link so if u wanted to check remove the spaces)

always returns false at all forms

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Option 1**
Use

```
matcher1 = Regex.Matcher(Url,Pattern,RegexOptions.IgnoreCase)
```

### OR

**Option 2**
Use

```
Dim Pattern As String=$"^(https:\/\/t\.me\/|https:\/\/telegram\.me\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15}[a-zA-Z0-9]$"$
```

Instead of

```
Dim Pattern As String=$"^(https:\/\/t\.me\/|https:\/\/telegram\.me\/)[a-z0-9_]{3,15}[a-z0-9]$"$
```

I hope both solutions are self explanatory!

**EDIT**

After OP accepted the answer, just a little bit of explanation. The `LineBegin ^` and `LineEnd $` identifiers are recognised only in `MULTILINE` mode otherwise they are ignored.

Comment: I changed the code :
 Sub Validate(Url As String)As String
 Dim Pattern As String=$"^(https:\/\/t\.me\/|https:\/\/telegram\.me\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15}[a-zA-Z0-9]$"$
 Dim matcher1 As Matcher
 matcher1 = Regex.Matcher(Url,Pattern)
 Return matcher1.Find
End Sub
still not working on a url like https :// telegram.me / meysam

Comment: Can you also use `RegexOptions.Multiline`

Comment: Use the multiline option where I used IgnoreCase in my answer.

Comment: I wish it was throwing an error instead of returning `False` :-)

Answer (score 1):

tnx to @bulbus the solution for anyone that may face this problem is:

```
 Sub Validate(Url As String)As String
    Dim Pattern As String=$"^(https:\/\/t\.me\/|https:\/\/telegram\.me\/)[a-zA-Z0-9_]{3,15}[a-zA-Z0-9]$"$
    Dim matcher1 As Matcher
    matcher1= Regex.Matcher2(Pattern,Regex.MULTILINE,Url)
    Return matcher1.Find
End Sub
```